# Negative values not reflecting in the output

Tags: c#

I have a database column which takes values `1`,`0`,`-1`. I am using `uint` and `GetUInt16` as seen below in my class and code snippet. Somehow the negative value isn't reflected. What datatype I should use to see the negative values in the class and in `rdr`?

```
public class Postcommit
{
    public string software_image_build { get; set; }
    public uint TestStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Code snippet:

```
  PCS[i++].TestStatus = rdr.GetUInt16(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using a `uint`. the `u` stands for `unsigned` meaning it can't be negative (the "sign" refers to the "negative sign"). You should use a normal `int`. Similarly, you should use `rdr.GetInt16(1)` to get the value.

```
public class Postcommit
{
    public string software_image_build { get; set; }
    public int TestStatus { get; set; }
}

...

PCS[i++].TestStatus = rdr.GetInt16(1);
```

So at every step along the way, from your database to your code, every single type must be set to an integer, *not* an unsigned integer.

Comment: @Vanna what's your point? It shouldn't be unsigned regardless.

Comment: @Stefan what do you mean?

Comment: @Soviut: `PCS[i++].TestStatus` is also of type `uint`, so `PCS[i++].TestStatus = rdr.GetInt16(-1);` wouldn't fit.

Comment: I kind of figured that would be obvious given the type matching and the explanation of int vs uint, but I've updated the code with the complete block.

Comment: @Soviut - that didn't help,i still get `1` even though the value is `-1`

Comment: @dotnet did you change the database storage to int as well?

Answer (score 5):

Range of `UInt16` is 0 to 65,535. It doesn't cover negative values. You should try the regular `Int16`.

Comment: @Stefan- was typo. Now rectified.